# How to stop the browser filling inputs with data

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Here's the scenario: I login to my site, at which point the browser asks me if I would like to save my details, I click yes. Later on I wish to change my password, so I go to the change password page. The browser automatically assumes the 'old password' input box is a login box and puts in the current password. This means all I have to do is type in a new password twice and the password will be changed.

It is easy to see how this is a potential security risk... I have tried a couple methods to override this which were:

- Explicitly setting the input value to blank in HTML.
- Setting autocomplete to off in HTML.
- Using Javascript to set the value to blank (on page load, click, setTimeout).

None of my attempts thus far have worked. So my question is: Is there a cross browser solution that allows a developer to override/specifically declare where passwords should and shouldn't be filled in by the browser?

Comment: Yes I'm on Mavericks.

Comment: If you are talking about Chrome, then no not really.  There are some hacks (adding hidden inputs) but they're not nice.

Comment: Unfortunately I thought that this may be the case, thanks.

Comment: You ll probably have to go to chrome://settings/ if using chrome (settings->advanced settings->Passwords and Forms) and disable  autofill :/ Same setting in Safari in Autofill tab

Comment: You could change the name of the inputs so autofill doesn't recognize them. But that will get messy in the backend I guess.

Comment: That's something else I have tried but forgotten to mention, it seems browsers only detect by `type` rather than by `id`.

Comment: duplicate problem Search first please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: Can you post some specific examples of what you've tried?  I'm pretty sure I've seen the ability to disable autocomplete on "profile update" pages before...

Comment: You could also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074985/disable-autofill-on-a-web-form-through-html-or-javascript  unless I'm misunderstanding your aim...

Answer (score 0):

**Example (of what to do):**
`<input type="text" value="" placeholder=""></input>`

Hope it helped

Comment: Unfortunately, as stated in my question, this method didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Just add **autocomplete="off"** so the browser not touch your box anymore.

```
<input type="text" name="xxx" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: As I stated in my question, my attempt of this method did not work. (Tested on OS X using Chrome)

Comment: well, what about using jquery to reset the form on page load? `$('form').each(function() { this.reset() });`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that, backed up by the research I have done and the response to my question, the answer is that there isn't currently a reliable, cross browser solution for this problem.