# Disable input text suggestions in Edge?

Tags: html, input, microsoft-edge

I have built a textbox dropdown AngularJS component which works great in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Internet Explorer.

A feature of this component is that you type in a string, and then can use the up/down arrow keys to scroll through suggestions.

In Microsoft Edge, as soon as you hit the down arrow, the following text is added to the input box:

> briefly explain your changes (corrected spelling, fixed grammar, improved formatting)

Is there anything I can do client side to stop this from happening?

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" />    
</form>
```

To demonstrate this, run the above snipper, type something into the textbox and hit the down arrow twice on Edge. I want this to not happen, as it is breaking my autocomplete!

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an input? If not, what type of element are you using? Are you trying to fix this issue whatever way possible or with an Angular.js solution?

Comment: A bog standard text input, to build the component, can post some code if you wish?

Comment: Might as well, not sure what a "bog" standard text input is to be completely honest. I'm assuming that was a typo and you're just talking about a regular text input. Please post the code and I will follow up. I'm going to assume, it's a simple "autocomplete" setting solution.

Comment: Apologies, it's an irish colloquialism, posted an example

Comment: its not a problem at all, I just wanted to clarify to make sure I was giving you accurate information. Did that solution work? If so, could you please accept the answer so the topic is closed?

Comment: Using the `aria-autocomplete` attribute, as suggested in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73691203/1694840 , disables the autocomplete for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are having an issue with the autocomplete feature. Simple add "autocomplete='off'" to your input and that should disable the feature.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: This won't work on any modern browser. Try using decoy fields. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2555771/317908

Comment: In Edge, if you backspace and delete the contents of the input, Edge will then display the autocomplete box.  So while this attribute helps, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: I just found that Microsoft disabled the "autocomplete=off" attribute.  What a terrible decision.  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9847360/

Comment: @Brain2000 - Is this for all Microsoft browsers or just below edge?

Comment: @rockmandew Just Edge.  IE 11 still works.  I found the suppression works on Edge to some extent, as the autocomplete can still appear if you tab into an input and press backspace to remove the contents.

Comment: @Brain2000 Chrome ignores autocomplete=off as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off

Answer (score 33):

For anyone experiencing autofill ignoring the `autocomplete="off"` on Edge 105+, you can use `aria-autocomplete="none"` alongside, which will prevent autofill from showing up (Tested in macOS 12.5 but should work in other platforms)

Comment: It works for me on Edge Version 105.0.1343.42, how do you know this way?

Comment: I read a couple of blog posts/chrome issues on auto completion vs autofill and someone mentioned the aria-autocomplete attribute, for which I read the doc and tested. Sure enough, Edge doesn't ignore such attribute when dealing with autofill

Comment: Adding the `aria-autocomplete` solved it for me on Windows 10 running Edge Version 105.0.1343.42. This answer should probably be promoted to the accepted solution.

Comment: I was going crazy because all of my old workarounds stopped working and none of the other suggestions I could find worked. aria-autocomplete worked for me in Windows 10, Edge Version 106.0.1370.37

Comment: autocomplete="off" + aria-autocomplete="none" no longer works for us on Edge version 112.0.1722.34

Comment: Working perfectly on Edge Version 114.0.1823.67 (Official build) (64-bit), Windows 11

Comment: Working on Edge 117, Mac

Answer (score 27):

Unfortunately, none of the above suggestions worked for me in latest Edge. However, this solution does:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" list="autocompleteOff" 
    id="fieldId" name="fieldname" placeholder="Placeholder here" />
```

This forces Edge to find a data lookup list called `autocompleteOff` which doesn't exist. Works a treat for me.

Added advantage is that it's pure HTML, no CSS or JS required.

**2021 update:**

Another solution which works very well for me is to add the `readonly` attribute to the field and then remove the tag using JQuery after a short delay of a few ms. The `readonly` attributes causes Edge (and others) to ignore the field.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: On **Edge Chromium**, use `list="autocompleteOff" ` because `autocomplete="off"` is inoperent.

Comment: Edge Chromium I am not finding this to work, sadly.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Edge
Version 102.0.1245.33 (Official build) (64-bit), this solution is not working. 
DATE: 10th-JUNE-2022

Answer (score 8):

From Mozilla:
You can set the autocomplete on the actual form tag `<form autocomplete='off' ... >...</form>` which will work for the entire form, or on individual `<input type='text' />` tags.

In my experience on IE 11 and Edge putting it on the form works but individual tags does not work. I tried testing on Chrome but the fields were already not autocompleting.

Please read the full [Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) for more detailed information.

**NOTE**

Most browsers disregard this for login fields.

Comment: In Edge it worked only when put on form, not individual elements, thanks

Answer (score 4):

if you want to remove autocomplete at the input in chrome when you use `autocomplete="off"` also you must remove id, if you don't remove `id` on your input, autocomplete will not work!

simple example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" list="autocompleteOff" 
     name="fieldname" placeholder="Placeholder here" />
```

you can handle your input with name ;) , that work for me fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

> If you are defining a user management page where a user can specify a new password for another person, and therefore you want to prevent autofilling of password fields, you can use autocomplete="new-password"

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

It works also for non-password fields.

Answer (score 2):

if you need it app/site-wide you can use jquery:

```
$('input').attr('autocomplete','off');
```

Or if you're like me and using **Angular+ui-router** you might try the following:

In your `index.html` add the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

Then to cover state changes, add the following to your root controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
                }, 2000);
            });
```

The timeouts are for the html to render before applying the jquery.

If you find a better solution please let me know.

Comment: What if it takes 2001 milliseconds to finish rendering every once in a while?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for Edge & Chrome (not a login form tho, not sure if that makes a difference)

```
autocomplete="somerandomstring"
```

https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8#gistcomment-2367048

Comment: it only works until you encounter the same `somerandomstring` more than once on the same computer. Perhaps if you use the current timestamp as the autocomplete....

Answer (score 1):

Just `autocomplete="off" list="autocompleteOff"` in your input and work done !

Answer (score 1):

autocomplete="off" doesn't work since yesterday (edge 105.0.1343.25).
Looks like a bug to me. Hopefully, they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

In the form field, try autocomplete="-"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34650823)

Answer (score 0):

try using a `<textarea>`, i think the only thing you can't do is make it `type="password"` to hide the text, otherwise it seems to stop autocomplete completely.

Answer (score -2):

in edge worked for me

```
`autocomplete="false" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" /
```

`according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30344707/14913109