# Prevent chrome from autofilling creditcard info

Tags: html, google-chrome, autofill

I have a `<input type="text" name="quantity" />` on my checkout form, and somehow Chrome thinks that this field is a credit card expiration month.

Once a user starts typing in his name (into another field), Chrome offers to fill in the CC info but when the user clicks on it, Chrome fills my quantity -`<input>` with the expiration date.

I've tried every possible workaround including:

- `autocomplete="off"` (doesn't work in Chrome completely)
- setting the `autocomplete="new-password"` (doesn't work for CC-autocomplete)

PS. if you're considering marking this question as "duplicate" please note that I specifically talk about credit-card autocomplete, not your usual autofill.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable autofill on a web form through HTML or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074985/disable-autofill-on-a-web-form-through-html-or-javascript)

Comment: @developernator like I indicated in the question, it's not a usual autocomplete, it's a "saved credit card" autocomplete.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code sample then please :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I just run into this exact same issue. 

And for anyone else ending up here, autocomplete="off" doesn't work.

Comment: Any update on this, I'm trying to fix this too, but not working for me! :(

Comment: @jazzcat, I'm having the same problem. Using autocomplete="anything" doesn't work. Did you solve it? How?

Answer (score 1):

Add `autocomplete="nope"`, to your input tag if you don't want it to auto-populate with anything. The browser will try to process it and since `nope` is not an acceptable option for it the browser will give up on processing it.

See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#Disabling_autocompletion.

Comment: That's hilarious.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found that is actually working with `chrome 89.0.4xxxx`

> `<input style="display: none;" autocomplete="cc-csc"/>`

How is this solution intended to work:
Basically, we give an alternative for chromium browsers to match by a specific autocomplete key (`cc-csc`) and not one that is more generic (`number`) by name or other secondary looked-up data.

You can find details on the topic [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1133769)

Here you can find a fixed example, comment out line with the fix to compare:
https://jsfiddle.net/bogdanm/sj0ewfqv/7/

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the form seems to work for me.

```
<input style="display: none;" autocomplete="cc-exp-month"/>
<input style="display: none;" autocomplete="cc-exp-year"/>
```

These fields have no effect but attracts the unwanted attention of the browser.

Answer (score -2):

I know this question has already been answered, but I'm going to put my two cents in anyway.

Another way to do this(as far as I know), is when making the `<input>` fields in your HTML document, just don't add the `type="ipsum dolor amet"` argument. Then Chrome, or any other browser, won't know what's what and will stay out of it.