# Why should I get this (in Chrome)?? 'Automatic credit card filling is ...'

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I wonder why I do get this [image: Error-alert in Chrome browser]

in Chrome browser.

This is very simple text box with no validation

[image]

If that matters, I am using MVC 5, with razor syntax and jQuery

### Edit:

Just checked, It's strangely coming only in ***this*** textbox, and not the rest.. so bit irking

**And,** [Prevent chrome from autofilling creditcard info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937170/prevent-chrome-from-autofilling-creditcard-info) didn't work

Comment: Because you're running on localhost without SSL.

Comment: Site doesn’t use https?

Comment: @RistoM That's ok, but what if it's not supposed to use SSL,

Comment: I did publish in UAT environment @stuartd , but it is still there.. and yes it **isn't** SSL

Comment: Why Chrome thinks it's a credit card is a [mystery](https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html#autofill).. see [Prevent chrome from autofilling creditcard info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937170/prevent-chrome-from-autofilling-creditcard-info) for a possible workaround

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the input or adding this tag to the input? 
autocomplete="off"