# Is possible to disable fill payment forms for the entire body (including a inner iFrame)?

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

My app has Stripe Card element, every time the user click in this element my Chrome display a list of Cards in my account to be selected.
I've contacted Stripe Dev team and it's not possible to disable it while creating the element. They have suggested to set "autocomplete='off'" in the parent Form of this card element. It doesn't work. I believe because the Card Element is inside of iFrame, any setting from my app form won't be passed to Stripe Card Element.

So I'm wondering if I can add a meta tag or JS command to avoid trigger Chrome (and Safari) saved card details.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might be helpful: https://terrylinooo.github.io/jquery.disableAutoFill/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: See also [Prevent chrome from autofilling creditcard info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39937170/215552)

Comment: Thanks for those suggestion, But I don't think I'm duplicating a query. I'm not looking for a "<input autocomplete='off' />"> I'm looking for a generic way that disable the browser option to display the cards in any input, including the iFramed inputs.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Not really, @Colfah. I've parked this task. I tried many things but no success by the time I was trying to fix it. Maybe there's a solution from the Browsers update, I just stoped searching for it. If I come back to this task and fix I let can update here.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was trying to do this because there was a bug whereby the card number wasn't entered into the card number input box after the customer selected their card. This fixed itself when I updated to latest version of react (just in case you are looking for solution to similar problem)

Answer (score -2):

You could turn off the auto-filling in the chrome settings. Tested and it is working for me

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggesting it, but I can't ask to every user of my app to turn off "Save and fill payment methods" only when they navigate to my app page. I need a solution that will be implemented by the Dev.