# Disable autofill on an input element in 2022

Tags: html

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this in 2022?

The old [`autocomplete="off"` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074985/disable-autofill-on-a-web-form-through-html-or-javascript) doesn't work, and [assigning a non-typical name / id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66719393/4381332) is an inadequate workaround.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I have an old trick that I use .. I am not sure if it still works, but: `autocomplete="iasnsdijsdn"`  The random characters seem to "trick" Chrome into not remembering ..

Comment: Wow! That worked - in Edge. Untested past that. Post as an answer, and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @Zak am just curious, would that also trick other browsers ? Especially the non-chrominium ones like `Firefox`.

Comment: @ths it used to on any Chromium based browsers  .. Yes .. I am not sure about Safari and FF though ..

Comment: @Zak am talking about the other ones, non-chrominium ? Do you confirm it works there too ?

Comment: $ths OP has confirmed Chrome and Edge.

Answer (score 3):

A work around that I've been using for years is

```
autocomplete="iasnsdijsdn"
```

For some reason the random string tricks Chrome into forgetting the field.

Comment: This disables "autofill" (when the field is simply focused), but not "autocomplete" (once 3 characters show up, autocomplete is back)

Answer (score 0):

For those having problems with `search` inputs in 2023, avoid using `name="search"`.

Chrome might auto-fill:

```
<input type="search" name="search">
```

Chrome does not auto-fill:

```
<input type="search" name="query">
<input type="search" name="s">
<input type="search" name="something_else">
```

My current Chrome v. 120.0.6099.71 - 64bit